# No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, database, docker

I want to run a sql file in php with seeder but I get an error, when you have the file sometimes it sees it sometimes it doesn't

How can I fix. thank you
you can see the screenshot below.

This Seeder:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class AddressSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::statement("SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1677721654546");
        DB::statement("SET wait_timeout = 100000");

        DB::unprepared(file_get_contents(database_path() . '/db/country.sql'));
        DB::unprepared(file_get_contents(database_path() . '/db/province.sql'));
        DB::unprepared(file_get_contents(database_path() . '/db/district.sql'));
        DB::unprepared(file_get_contents(database_path() . '/db/district-1.sql'));
        DB::unprepared(file_get_contents(database_path() . '/db/neighborhood.sql'));
    }
}
```

This ls result

```
/var/www# ls database/db
ls: cannot access 'database/db/district.sql': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'database/db/neighborhood.sql': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'database/db/province.sql': No such file or directory
country.sql  district-1.sql  district.sql  neighborhood.sql  province.sql
```

This Error

```
In AddressSeeder.php line 30:
                                                                                                          
  file_get_contents(/var/www/database/db/province.sql): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

[image]

Comment: The fact that you're getting that error on a simple `ls` means it's an odd system issue, not a coding issue.

Comment: @aynber I think so too but I don't know what to do

Answer (score -1):

its because you're in one folder trying to get to another folder without going a step back first.

use ../ in the qry where you choose your folder.

Comment: But if it is, it shouldn't see any files in ls